# Review ban from missing choice (traffic control change?)

Tags: support

I was tooling through "Late Answers" and hit [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/12986683).  I flagged it as "Very Low Quality".  I got a red box telling me that the answer was deleted.  I'm used to this immediately bringing up the "you passed" page.  Instead, the page then gave me two choices: no action required & skip ("I'm done" was grayed out).  Since I'd obviously reviewed correctly, I clicked the first choice to go through.  I now have a review ban.  Would someone please reverse this?

Comment: `Would someone please reverse this?` while I sympathize, it take more than one failed audit to get banned,  How many others did you fail?

Comment: Regardless of the possible red box issue: 1. A single failed review alone never leads to a ban, and 2. When reviewing link-only answers like that one, *always* prefer to skip rather than mark it as no action required.

Comment: Unbanned, because this is a REALLY annoying bug. Next time, consider editing.

Comment: Yes, I did learn from this one.  I believe that I've had only one other review failure in the past week, and two more early in the month (2-day ban).  I try to do a lot of reviewing, and I've generally not bothered to contest the assessments -- I just spend my time reviewing on other help sites until the ban is lifted.  When SO implements a specific appeal method, I'll use that instead of going elsewhere.  I don't have the skills to implement said change, so I'll just be patient.  This one just looked like a bug (plus my fatal error in that click).